# Replace specific line in txt file with multiple list elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a text file with this structure:

```
foo
bar
Important line
none
```

And I want to replace the none with multiple list elements so the text file looks like this:

```
foo
bar
Important line
E:\\gaz.txt    
E:\\bar.txt
E:\\foo.txt
```

However, the original file contains *several* `none` string, I want only this one to be removed.

I can add the list elements under `Important line`, but I have no clue how to properly remove the `none` string without directly calling the line number (the list with filenames is dynamic, so it varies):

```
import fileinput

files_txt = ['E:\\foo.txt', 'E:\\bar.txt', 'E:\\gaz.txt']

for line in fileinput.input('E:\\inputfile.txt', inplace=1):
    print line,
    if line.startswith('Important line'):        
        for filelist in reversed(files_txt):
            print filelist
```

I found something like `print line.replace("none", "files_txt"),` but this didn't work properly (or I just don't know where to put it correctly).

Comment: @Jacques Gaudin No, i found this thread, but I don't want to delete the row based on the line number (as stated in my post), but rather replace it directly after a `line.startswith` condition.

Comment: Understood but the accepted answer doesn't use the line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import fileinput

files_txt = ['E:\\foo.txt', 'E:\\bar.txt', 'E:\\gaz.txt']
should_skip_none = False

for line in fileinput.input('E:\\inputfile.txt', inplace=True):
    if line.startswith('none') and should_skip_none:
        should_skip_none = False
        continue
    else:
        print line
        if line.startswith('Important line'):
            should_skip_none = True        
            for filelist in reversed(files_txt):
                print filelist
```

Comment: This removes ALL `none` strings in the file, however. I want ONLY the `none` string under the `Important line` string replaced.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Oh and for python 2.7 it's `print line,` instead of `print(line, end='')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import fileinput

files_txt = ['E:\\foo.txt', 'E:\\bar.txt', 'E:\\gaz.txt']
for line in fileinput.input("E:\\inputfile.txt", inplace=True):
    if line.startswith("none"):
        print(line.replace("none", ''), end='')
    elif line.startswith('Important line'):
        print(line)
        for filelist in reversed(files_txt):
            print(filelist)
    else:
        print(line)
```